# How can I remove numbers after a specific character with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I need to modify a .fasta file that looks like this:

```
>Contig_1;2
AGATC...
>Contig_2;345
AaGGC...
>Contig_3;22
GGAGA...
```

And transform it into something like:

```
>Contig_1
AGATC...
>Contig_2
AaGGC...
>Contig_3
GGAGA...
```

I tried doing the following, but it did not work as intended.

```
sed -i 's/;*\n/\n/g' file.fasta
```

Could someone give me some advice? Thanks!

Comment: `sed 's/;.*$//g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i 's/;[^;]*$//' file.fasta
```

See the [online demo](https://s=%27%3EContig_1;2%20AGATC...%20%3EContig_2;345%20AaGGC...%20%3EContig_3;22%20GGAGA...%27%20sed%20%27s/;%5B%5E;%5D*$//%27%20%3C%3C%3C):

```sh
s='>Contig_1;2
AGATC...
>Contig_2;345
AaGGC...
>Contig_3;22
GGAGA...'
sed 's/;[^;]*$//' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
>Contig_1
AGATC...
>Contig_2
AaGGC...
>Contig_3
GGAGA...
```

Note that `sed` does not place the newline into the pattern space (since you are using a GNU `sed`, you could force it to do so with `-z`, but it is not necessary here), and you can't match a newline with `\n` in your sed command.

The `;[^;]*$` pattern matches

- `;` - a semi-colon
- `[^;]*` - any zero or more chars other than `;` (if you need to make sure you match digits, replace with `[0-9]*` or `[[:digit:]]*`)
- `$` - end of string.

Note you need no `g` flag here since this command needs to perform a single replacement per line.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** You can keep it very simple with `awk`. Written with your shown samples, in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F';' '/^>/{NF=1} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting field separator as `;` for all the lines. In main program checking condition if line starts from `>` then set `NF`(number of fields) to 1 which will keep values just before first occurrence of `;`.

---

---

***2nd solution*** you want to look for all types of lines(either start with `>` or not) and you need values just before first occurrence of `;` then try following solution:

```
awk -F';' '/;/{NF=1} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the combination of `cat` command and `awk` to display the output.

```
cat filename | awk -F ';' '{print $1}'
```

Here ';' will be taken as a file separator and then only first field will be displayed on the screen.